# Mapping JPA Composite Foreign Key

Tags: java, jpa

I'm new with JPA, and want to create a Database with this relation :

```
|Participant|
|id : INT (PK) | id_event : INT (PK, FK) |

|Event|
|id : INT (PK) |
```

I'm totally lost and barely figure the syntax of the examples I found :/

But I understood I need to create an other class to contain the two pieces of the PK, which leads to another question : can this class be an inner-class (for optimisation purposes) ?

I hope I'm not asking too much but I really want to get it.

Comment: Participant and Event have a ManyToMany relation? Then you need another entity, and this new entity will need to include the two IDs as a composite primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entities might be like this:

```
@Entity
public class Participant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    // or any other relation
    private List<Event> events;

    // fields, constructors, getters, setters
}

@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // fields, constructors, getters, setters
}
```

In this case JPA will create 3 tables with the following queries (SQL dialect will vary from DB to DB, in this case I used H2 database):

```
CREATE TABLE Event (
  id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Participant (
  id bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Participant_Event (
  Participant_id bigint NOT NULL,
  events_id      bigint NOT NULL
)
```

`Participant_Event` is automatically created join table to link participants and events.

Here is a good example of understanding [JPA entity relations](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it says to me `The type of field "x.x.x.x.Participant.event" isn't supported by declared persistence strategy "OneToMany".  Please choose a different strategy.` :(

Comment: please try again, I updated my answer. But actually I don't know what relationships you have to use, it depends on your goals and requirements. You can read the article and decide. Another good illustrated tutorial is [JPA - Entity Relationships](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm).

Comment: Well.. It said `"x.x.x.x.Participant.events" declared that it is mapped by "participant", but that is a not a field of the related type.` So I tried with **id** instead but then it said `Collection field "x.x.x.x.Participant.events" declares that it is mapped by "x.x.x.x.Event.id", but this is not a valid inverse relation.` I'm completely lost I have to admit...

Comment: Please don't be upset, I removed the mapping and add the description of what tables will be created, please look again, now it works.

Comment: Ok, that seems really close except that it's writing the id in another row ^^ Anyway I'll look deeper in it but that seems the correct way for my problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For a OneToMany relation you need the below entities and tables:

- Participant
- Event

The `Event` entity is simple:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    // fields, constructors, getters, setters
}
```

The entity `Participant` has to hold the **composite key** (aka two pieces of the PK), so, every `Participant` is only linked once with an Event.

```
@Entity
public class Participant {
    @EmbeddedId
    private EventParticipantPK id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Event> events;

    // fields, constructors, getters, setters
}
```

The composite key is declared as an `EmbeddedId`.

The EventParticipantPK should be like:

```
@Embeddable
public class EventParticipantPK {
    @Column (name = "PARTICIPANT_ID")
    private Long participantId;

    @Column (name = "EVENT_ID")
    private Long eventId;

    // fields, constructors, getters, setters
}
```

I hope this helps.